# How to remove country code from phone number like example: (855)905649832, +855 98675432 flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, phone-number

```
RegExp reExp = RegExp(r'^(0|\+|(\+[0-9]{2,4}|\(\+?[0-9]{2,4}\)) ?)([0-9]*|\d{2,4}-\d{2,4}(-\d{2,4})?)$');
String phoneNumber = phoneNumberOne.text.replaceFirst(reExp, '');
```

Comment: In your question title, are you showing the desired result?  In your question body, we'd like to see you full requirements, several sample inputs, and your exact desired outputs for those inputs.  Please read [ask] to learn how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I think what are you looking for is the following:

You have this input:

```
+855 98675432
(855) 98675432
055 98675432
```

and you want to get the output as below:

```
98675432
98675432
98675432
```

The regex to do that:

```dart
void main() {
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'^((0[0-9]{2,4}|\+[0-9]{2,4}|\(\+?[0-9]{2,4}\)) ?)');

  String firstNumber = "+855 98675432".replaceFirst(regExp, '');
  print(firstNumber);

  String secondNumber = "(855) 98675432".replaceFirst(regExp, '');
  print(secondNumber);

  String thirdNumber = "055 98675432".replaceFirst(regExp, '');
  print(thirdNumber);
}
```

Explanation:
`^` means that the string should be at the beginning.
`(0[0-9]{2,4}` means 0 then two to four numbers in this range 0 to 9.
`|` means or.
`\+[0-9]{2,4}` means + then two to four numbers in this range 0 to 9.
`\(\+?[0-9]{2,4}\))` means + then two to four numbers in this range 0 to 9 in a parentheses.
 `?` means zero or one space.

The regex above can be even made shorter like this:

```
^(\(?(0|\+|)[0-9]{2,4}\)?) ?
```

But it's a little bit harder to read.

Comment: Hello sir it working it (855) and + 855, And how about other country code how we should prevent? example +234 xxx xxx xxx, +84 xxx xxx xxx etc..

Comment: For substring it's an okay brother, but one more if user input as like +(2345)xxx xxx xxx, How can we prevent?

Comment: You can remove the ` ?` at the end for that.  
`^((0[0-9]{2,4}|\+[0-9]{2,4}|\(\+?[0-9]{2,4}\)))`